# Unable to swipe the screens horizontally

Tags: android, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

Helo Evryone!

I am trying to add "swipe" functionality in my app but i am unable to do so. I have stories to swipe left to right and vice versa. I have written a sub class MYGestureListener which has the following implementation.

```
 class MyGestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        Log.e("Now", "onFling");

        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;

            // right to left swipe
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                // checking if current index is the last index
                if (ind == items.size() - 1 || ind > items.size() - 1) {
                    Log.e("Last Index", "Can't move further anymore");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    ind++;
                    loadAndShowNextActivity();
                }
            }
            // left to right
            else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                if (ind <= 0) {
                    Log.d("First Index", "Can't move back anymore");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    ind--;
                    loadAndShowNextActivity();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception occured while flinging");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then i have overriden onTouchEvent() Function in main class. which is implemented as follows:

```
  @Override

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    Log.e("Now","onTouchEvent");
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

and then calling its instance in onCreate of the main class as follows:

```
  gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureListener());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

It's not working, please suggest and identify where am i going wrong. Thanks in Advance..:-)

Comment: @Raghu .. No error. but functionality is not being achieved. When i swipe through nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a code like below

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener;
import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class SwipetestActivity extends Activity{
    private static final String LOGID = "CHECKTHISOUT";
    public int[] list = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e };
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
    private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    public int i = 0;

    String message = "Initial Message"; 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageview.setImageResource(list[0]);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    }

    public class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener implements OnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            try {
                if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                    return false;
                // right to left swipe
                if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    if(list.length>i){
                        i++;
                    imageview.setImageResource(list[i]);
                    }
                    Log.v(LOGID,"right to left swipe detected");


                } // left to right swipe 
                else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    ImageView imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    if(i>0){
                        i--;
                    imageview.setImageResource(list[i]);
                    }
                    Log.v(LOGID,"left to right swipe detected");                    


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // nothing
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    // This doesn't work
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)){
            Log.v(LOGID,"screen touched");
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: @Mayu...I tried this but the result is same, emulator screen shows the signs of touch but do not swipe the content. because onTouchEvent is called every time i try to swap. Can it be an issue with emulator...??? It may run fine on device...???

Comment: if you check the logcat you can see the swap events are recorded in emulator too but swap (fling as android call it) is more accurate in Real Device than emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
  public class Main extends Activity {

private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 200;
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
private Animation slideLeftIn;
private Animation slideLeftOut;
private Animation slideRightIn;
private Animation slideRightOut;
private ViewFlipper viewFlipper;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    viewFlipper = (ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.flipper);
    slideLeftIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_in);
    slideLeftOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_left_out);
    slideRightIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_in);
    slideRightOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.slide_right_out);

    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        try {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
                return false;
            // right to left swipe
            if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideLeftIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideLeftOut);
                viewFlipper.showNext();
            }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                viewFlipper.setInAnimation(slideRightIn);
                viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(slideRightOut);
                viewFlipper.showPrevious();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // nothing
        }
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
    }
```

slide_left_in.xml

```
             <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="800"/>
            </set>
```

slide_left_out.xml

```
                 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
               <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
           <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="-100%p" android:duration="800"/>
            </set>
```

slide_right_in.xml

```
              <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="800"/>
           </set>
```

slide_right_out.xml

```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <translate android:fromXDelta="0" android:toXDelta="100%p" android:duration="800"/>
             </set>
```